# Groovy ws-lite REST post with json payload

Tags: groovy

I am trying to call a REST API via the ws-lite.  Get works great but calling a post with a json payload not working.  Bit of a noob but from github notes wiki i am not sure https://github.com/jwagenleitner/groovy-wslite

```
@Grab('com.github.groovy-wslite:groovy-wslite:1.1.2')
import wslite.rest.*
import groovy.json.JsonBuilder
def client = new    RESTClient("https://d.la10.salesforceliveagent.com/chat/rest")
def response = client.get(path:'/System/SessionId', headers:['X-LIVEAGENT-    API-VERSION':'36','X-LIVEAGENT-AFFINITY':'null'])

def skey = response.json.key
def sid = response.json.id
def stoken = response.json.affinityToken


client.post(path:'/Chasitor/ChasitorInit', headers:['X-LIVEAGENT-API-VERSION':'36','X-LIVEAGENT-SESSION-KEY':skey,'X-LIVEAGENT-AFFINITY':stoken,'X-LIVEAGENT-SEQUENCE':'1'])
{
    type ContentType.application/json
         json {
             "organizationId": "00D28000000f5N9",
             "deploymentId": "572280000008R6L",
             "buttonId": "573D000000000OC",
             "agentId": "005B0000000F3b2",
             "doFallback": true,
             "sessionId": sid,
             "userAgent": "Lynx/2.8.8",
             "screenResolution": "2560x1440",
             "visitorName": "Jon A",
             "prechatDetails": [],"prechatEntities": [],
             "receiveQueueUpdates": true,
             "isPost": true
         }
}
```

Curious if anyone has an example using for a post with REST via ws-lite from groovy.  I simply get compilation failures based on the json format.   Any insight appreciated

Answer (score 1):

The `json` method inside the `post` block is expecting a Map as the parameter so the following would work (basically change the braces to brackets):

```
....
....
client.post(path:'/Chasitor/ChasitorInit', headers:['X-LIVEAGENT-API-VERSION':'36','X-LIVEAGENT-SESSION-KEY':skey,'X-LIVEAGENT-AFFINITY':stoken,'X-LIVEAGENT-SEQUENCE':'1'])
{
    type ContentType.application/json
        json ["organizationId": "00D28000000f5N9",
             "deploymentId": "572280000008R6L",
             "buttonId": "573D000000000OC",
             "agentId": "005B0000000F3b2",
             "doFallback": true,
             "sessionId": sid,
             "userAgent": "Lynx/2.8.8",
             "screenResolution": "2560x1440",
             "visitorName": "Jon A",
             "prechatDetails": [],"prechatEntities": [],
             "receiveQueueUpdates": true,
             "isPost": true]
}
```

Since the Map is the only parameter you should also be able to omit the brackets.